# java null pointer exception at at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)

Tags: android, sqlite, pointers, exception, null

```
public  String getValue()
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = String.format("SELECT %sFROM %s ", NUMBER_PASSWD,PASSWORD_TABLE);
        db.close();
        Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG,"Sending Value");
        return sql;

    }
```

I am having a problem with this part of the code where I am trying to check the values in the database and retrieve it

Comment: Please post your stack trace.

Comment: You're missing a space after the first '%s'. But also, this is returning the SQL statement, not the value from the database. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: the statement must return a value which is later on converted to string urinf the String.format and stored in sql . Isn't it right

Answer (score -1):

```
Your_sqliteadminClass admin = new Your_sqliteadminClass(this, name_db, null,
            version_db);
 SQLiteDatabase db=admin.getReadableDatabase();
```

Comment: should that declaration be in my getValue() method I have initialized it in my class definition

Comment: I had to post another question please can you look it up